# Bulk update in django orm from dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a django dictionary which contains a value against row index and column index, you can think it as a two dimensional matrix. How we can bulk update the value in django.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please post your model, dictionary etc. whatever you did so far.

Comment: Please provide more details, model code, example code you have tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert dictionary structure to the JSON format as [django-fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/) structure and save these data to a file, then append this data to your project database by putting one of both:

1- put data to `app_name/fixture/initial_data.json` for append this data when running `./manage.py migrate`
2- appending this data to the project database by `./manage.py loaddata data_file_name.json` command.

Also if your dictionary is complex you can do this action in **django shell** by typing `./manage.py shell` and write import code.